# Display More information from inside Tab

Tags: usability, gui-design, ux-field, tabs, modal-windows

I am currently working on improving the usability of a new landing page. During the usability testing, I notice that users couldn't get more information out from the tab. Each tab represents certain university field and inside each field there are several modules/courses. The goal is to keep the user within the landing page and thus displaying the information regarding the course when the user requested.

The tab is located at the middle of the page and looks something like this: 
[image]

looking at the picture, if the user clicks on the 'course related to anatomy' then a dialog would appear. My question is

- Do you think a modal would solve the issue "Though, I dont prefer modal" !.

Please advice. Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to keep the user on the landing page?

Comment: @MattO'Keefe I wanted to keep the use in the landing page, so that they can do the required action that we intended/designed for them to do.

Comment: I would suggest not to keep the user within the landing page and to navigate to different pages as keeping the user on the landing page while presenting diverse information would only lead to more confusion and lack of backtrackability for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible options if you don't wish to go with modal dialog:

1) You can let the content work as [**accordion**](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#no-auto-height)

2) Let the user see the whole content on the same page but in different section with a back button, also make sure the functionality works even when the user uses Browser's back button:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here seems to replace the content of the tab with the course information or make this section a collapsable one, inside the tab.